# Keep the filename and filetype in AWS S3 upload using Camel

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

Being a beginner with AWS and S3, i was trying to integrate to upload a **Sample.txt** file from my local sftp to s3 using apache camel

```
<route>
        <from uri="sftp://testuser@localhost?password=test&amp;delete=true" />
        <setHeader name="CamelAwsS3Key">
            <constant>test</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="aws-s3://myTestBucket?accessKey=******&amp;secretKey=RAW(******)&amp;deleteAfterWrite=false&amp;region=AP_SOUTH_1" />
    </route>
```

This works but the file always uploads with the name **test** and type is also not shown.
Have tried multiple methods.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Well, you set the filename to be `test`  (the `CamelAwsS3Key` header).  About the type - you mean the Content-Type object property?

Comment: @gusto2 I had added the headerkey cause it showed as a mandatory value for the route. Type, yes. I thought the system will auto identify the type.  Is there any alternative i could provide ?

Comment: You can set the header using the `simple` expression to the  file name (I'm not sure where the sftp store the file name) and you may try to set the `CamelAwsS3ContentType` too http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/aws-s3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved when passing a the key and using the filename provided by SFTP simple

```
<route>
        <from uri="sftp://testuser@localhost?password=test&amp;delete=true" />
        <setHeader name="CamelAwsS3Key">
             <simple>${in.header.camelFileName}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="aws-s3://myTestBucket?accessKey=******&amp;secretKey=RAW(******)&amp;deleteAfterWrite=false&amp;region=AP_SOUTH_1" />
    </route>
```

Thanks to @gusto2 for the support.

Also, as an addition you can add to a specific folder the file on upload by changing ,

```
<simple>{foldername}/${in.header.camelFileName}</simple>
```